# How can I insert a transparent rectangle but with the edges mark?

Tags: modeling, edges

[image: full transparent rectangle with mark edges]

I want to do exactly what is shown in the image. Some know the way to do it?

Comment: "Exactly what is shown on image" - what exactly ? If you want to overlay one image on top of another then do you really need 3D modeling package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a bitmap, it could be better to just use a mesh, like this:

[image]

here I also used a shadless white material, to get the idea.

Another way could also be curves with tapers, probably...

Using real geometry, instead of having a fixed bitmap, allows you to adapt the mesh to different needs, and ensures optimal resolution...

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Box Masks* in the compositor.

Add two *Box Mask* nodes, make one of them slightly smaller and set it to subtract from the other *box mask*. Use the result as the *factor* input of a *Mix* node, where you mix the original image with the color you want the edge of the rectangle to be.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create the "Graphic" in an application like Photoshop or Gimp with an alpha channel. Save it in a format that supports alpha channels like .PNG. Then import that "Graphic" as a plane into Blender. In Blender you can go to "File" > "Import" select "Images as Planes" and check off "Use Alpha"in the import options.